# Show the same button in different mat-cards in the same component with different conditions

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and could use some help. I have this button which only appears in one card. However, I would like to show it in 4 different cards which all have different conditions. What is the best way to display the button in different cards on the same component?

```
<mat-card
  *ngIf="oldUsers && !!retiredUsers"
>
  <button
  mat-raised-button 
  (click)="openDialog()"
  [disabled]="newUser"
  >
   <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
   DELETE
  </button>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new component which will be your button. This component can have an `Input` where you can pass the condition for the disabled option. Of course, you can create other `Inputs` for different options.

button.component.ts:

```
@Input() disabled: boolean;
```

button.component.html:

```
  <button
   mat-raised-button 
   (click)="openDialog()"
   [disabled]="disabled"
   >
   <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
   DELETE
  </button>
```

in card components:

```
<app-button [disabled]="newUser"></app-button>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I will implement.